# How can I make MUI's Button with link look like normal Button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Button to download a file with a filename. To do that I wrote this:

```
<Button
  color='primary'
  href=`/apiproxy/objects/${id}/subobjects`
  LinkComponent={React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <Link {...props} type='text/csv' download={`object_${id}_subobjects.csv`} ref={ref} />)}
/>
```

The resulting element looks the same as my other Buttons which don't have href attribute (also with `color='primary'`), but on hover its text changes colour to blue, unlike with the other buttons, where it stays white.
How to make it styled the same as other Buttons? I can specify `&:hover` text colour to white, but that will break when theme changes the text colour of other buttons.

Is there a way to change the Link component to make it styled the same as other Buttons, or if not, what in the palette do Buttons use as their hover text colour so that I can set it to that?

Comment: @isherwood Can't he use a <Button component={Link} >.. ? With a Link component coming from react router dom or smth you could achieve this

Comment: What's the rendered output? Does it pass an HTML validation check? There's your answer.

Comment: I guess yes, It just render an <a> anchor with href property and some MUI style to make it look like a Button

Comment: I think we need to know the CSS styles that are applied to it already. There may be a CSS "variable" applied to the `color` property one could take advantage of.

Comment: @isherwood MUI's `Button` is just a UI component that supports rendering as an HTML button, as an HTML anchor (default when you specify the `href` attribute), or as any other root node you provide. There's no actual links inside buttons here, it's all officially supported features. It renders as an anchor. I expect a library as polished as MUI to not miss also styling the hover state, which is why I assume I'm missing something.
This would also be more obvious if you hadn't removed MUI from the question title.

Comment: Fair enough. Apologies for my misunderstanding. Don't tag titles, though. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `styledComponent` for Link component. like following...

```
const theme = useTheme();

const StyledLink = styled(Link)(({ theme, color = "primary" }) => ({
  ":hover": {
    color: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
}));

<Button
  color="primary"
  href="/apiproxy/objects/1/subobjects"
  LinkComponent={React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
    <StyledLink
      {...props}
      type="text/csv"
      download={"object_1_subobjects.csv"}
      ref={ref}
      theme={theme}
    />
  ))}
/>
```

You can set the hover color in palette in theme.js file and use that color like `theme.palette.${hoverColor}`

Please check this test component.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mui-28251-28335-forked-j2x8cd?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js

Comment: The OP already mentions using CSS to set the color of the text to "white" directly, but dismisses that because the theme may change such that the color of the text may no longer be white.

Comment: if so, we can use `styledComponent`. We can define `styledComponent` by using `styled()` . I updated the answer. please check

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I've been looking for! Though it seems that `Button`s set as primary use the primary palette, so using `theme.palette.primary.contrastText` instead of `theme.palette.secondary.main` gave me the result I wanted.

Comment: yeah. your way is perfect!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can make the button redirect them to a MediaFire where the file could be downloaded:

`<a href="link-to-media"><button class="buttonClass">Download</button></a>`

and then you can modify the buttonClass to be whatever you like.

Comment: This makes it unnecessarily inconvenient. As Heretic Monkey mentioned this can be achieved using css or as Green Dev answered using a `styledComponent`.

Comment: This markup is invalid (cfr. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element).